# Saving data with ajax to a database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How can I save info that I have in a div named '#time' to a database?

```
<div id="time" style="float:right;font-size:15px;">0:00:00</div>
```

The code above is a jq count up timer.
What I'm trying is to save every tick in the database.
How can I do this?

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "setupcounter.php",
                    data: {action: 'save',
                    field: $("#time").val(),},
                    success: function(msg){

                    }
                    error: function(){
                        alert('error');
                    }
                });
```

Comment: edited the post with the ajax i tried, i dont know what i need to write in the php file.

Comment: `$_POST[ 'field' ]` holds the data you are looking for. How to save an entry to a database is an entirely different subject. You should at least try something for yourself first. There's many tutorials to find on the subject.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Ajax POST example with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php)

Comment: @rein i know how to save it to the database, just asking how do i save it as a variable.

Comment: Where exactly does it go wrong? The data can be accessed from within your javascript by: `$("#time").val()`, once you made a successful post to your PHP script, you can access the posted data by using `$_POST['field']`.

Comment: Thats the php file code: 
`<?php
 echo $_POST[''];
?>`
all I tried was to echo it to check but i get undefined index.

Comment: on the chrome network i can see that the post was recived and i can see the correct time on the preview, but on the page I cant.

Comment: How about you actually echo what I told you to: `<?php echo $_POST['field']; ?>`

Comment: I tried it before and got the same error

Comment: `Notice: Undefined index: field in C:\xampp\htdocs\comp\setupcounter.php on line 1`

Answer (score 1):

Actually you want to get text of div. So do this..

Just replace

```
$("#time").val()
```

with

```
$("#time").text()
```

Comment: and how do i get it from the php file? $_POST what?

Comment: Should be: `$_POST["field"]`

Comment: Yes, you can get it in php as $_POST["field"]

Comment: `Notice: Undefined index: field in C:\xampp\htdocs\***\setupcounter.php on line 3`

Comment: and it made my xampp crash :/

Comment: That means your `$_POST` did not contain the value you were trying to get from it. Try to do a `var_dump( $_POST )` to see what's inside of your post.

Comment: you arent supposed to actually use $_POST['field'], roy. switch out field with whatever post param you actually use.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var time = $('#time').val();
        //Just add whatever params you need to the datastring variable.
         var dataString = 'time='+time+'&action=save';
        //Check console that you are sending the right data
        console.log(dataString) 
        $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "setupcounter.php",
             data: dataString,
             success: function(msg){
              console.log(msg);
              }
     });
```

In php you would do:

```
$time = $_POST['time'];
$action = $_POST['action'];
//Db stuff
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zrdk87ub/1/)

Comment: and i get on the php page undefined index again.

Comment: There's not really anything wrong with this. updated it and added a fiddle. mind you, theres no real .php to test it with in jsfiddle. i use this snippet all the time.